# Set Current Limiter for Stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor

I have `NEMA17` 3.57V 1.8A recommended voltage (8V~35V2A) stepper motor with `a4988` chip. I'm trying to find out what is the best setting for current limiter, but I'm not sure if I doing it right.

I'm also using `AC Adapter` as power supply with Output `12V 1.5A`. What is the number I should set the current limiter please?
I'm really not good in the stuffs like VREF etc.

using this[image]

Comment: The power supply is mandating the limit of 1.5A.  It will get annoyed if you go beyond that.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I would like to know a number for multimeter when using 20V mode, I set 0.72, but not sure if it match

Comment: What number are you referring to? Where do you set this?

Comment: I'm trying to set a current like in this link
https://ardufocus.com/howto/a4988-motor-current-tuning/

Comment: 0.8 would give a 1A limit or around 1.4A max.

Comment: So this is the right formula ? Vref = 1.8A * 8 * 0.1 => 1.44

, 0.1 Because my SMD resistor code is R100

Comment: should I set it on that value or bellow the value?